# Selenium not finding custom attribute 'data-target-section-id'

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to scrape some profiles of people in linkedin from a specific job. To do this I was trying to find the people button and click it to specifically look at the relevant people.

The path is as follows:

From signed out Linkedin home -> I sign in and go to LinkedIn home -> I write in the search bar "hr" and hit enter.

In the result page of hr, on the left side of the page, there is a navigation list that says "On this page". One of the options includes "People" and that is what I want to target.

The link to the page is: https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/all/?keywords=hr&origin=GLOBAL_SEARCH_HEADER&sid=Xj2

The HTML of the button for 'People' in the navigation list is:

```
<li>
   <button aria-current="false" class="search-navigation-panel_button" data-target-section-id="PTFmMNSPSz2LQRzwynhRBQ==" role="link" type="button"> People
```

I have tried to find this button through `By.Link_text` and found the keyword `People` but did not work. I have also tried to do `By.XPATH "//button[@data-target-section-id='RIK0XK7NRnS21bVSiNaicw==']")""` but it also does not find it.

How can I make selenium find this custom attribute so I can find this button through data-target-section-id="PTFmMNSPSz2LQRzwynhRBQ=="?

Another issue that I am having is that I can target all the relevant people on the page and loop through them but I cannot extract the link of each of the profiles. It only takes the first link of the first person and never updates the variable again through the loop.

For example, if the first person is Ian, and the second is Brian, it gives me the link for Ian's profile even if 'users' is Brian.

Debugging the loop I can see the correct list of people in all_users but it only gets the href of the first person in the list and never updates.

Here is the code of that:

```
all_users = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@class, 'entity-result__title-line entity-result__title-line--2-lines')]")

for users in all_users:
    print(users)
    get_links = users.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@href, 'miniProfileUrn')]")
    print(get_links.get_attribute('href'))
```

Comment: I see this button is inside of a list.  Is it visible without clicking a dropdown or mousing over something first?  If not, you may need to mouse over it first or click the dropdown first.

Comment: the list is visible on the page without having to click on a dropdown or mouse over anything.

Comment: I'm trying to find this HTML on various pages on linkedin.com but I can't seem to find the page you're talking about. Please link the actual page and clearly indicate which link you are trying to click. I have the solution to the second problem but don't want to start an answer until I have all the info I need.

Comment: @JeffC I updated the question with the link of the actual pages and hopefully a better explanation of what I want to click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the reason your People button locator isn't working is because the `data-target-section-id` is dynamic. Mine is showing as `hopW8RkwTN2R9dPgL6Fm/w==`. We can get around that by using an XPath to locate the element based on the text contained, "People", e.g.

```
//button[text()='People']
```

Turns out that matches two elements on the page because many of the left nav links are repeated as rounded buttons on the top of the page so we can further refine our locator to

```
//button[text()='People'][@data-target-section-id]
```

Having said that, that link only scrolls the page so you don't really need to click that.

From there, you want to get the links to each person listed under the People heading. We first need the DIV that contains the People section. It's kinda messy because the IDs on those elements are also dynamic so we need to find the H2 that contains "People" and then work our way back up the DOM to the DIV that contains only that section. We can get that using the XPath below

```
//div[@class='search-results-container']/div[.//h2[text()='People']]
```

From there, we want all of the A tags that uniquely link to a person... and there's a lot of A tags in that section but most are not ones we want so we need to do more filtering. I found that the below XPath locates each unique URL in that section.

```
//a[contains(@href,'miniProfileUrn')][contains(@class,'scale-down')]
```

Combining the two XPaths, we get

```
//div[@class='search-results-container']/div[.//h2[text()='People']]//a[contains(@href,'miniProfileUrn')][contains(@class,'scale-down')]
```

which locates all unique URLs belonging to a person in the People section of the page.

Using this, your code would look like

```
all_users = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='search-results-container']/div[.//h2[text()='People']]//a[contains(@href,'miniProfileUrn')][contains(@class,'scale-down')]")

for user in all_users:
    print(user.get_attribute('href'))
```

---

NOTE: The reason your code was only returning the first href repeatedly is because you are searching from an existing element with an XPath so you need to add a "." at the start of the XPath to indicate to start searching from the referenced element.

```
get_links = users.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//*[contains(@href, 'miniProfileUrn')]")
                                          ^ add period here
```

I've eliminated that step in my code so you won't need it there.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to locate several elements with the same attribute replace `find_element` with `find_elements`. See if that works to find not just the first element matching your search, but all elements with that attribute.

Review the [Selenium: Locating Elements documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) and see if you can try each and every option they have for locating elements.

Something else to try:

```
button_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@data-target-section-id='RIK0XK7NRnS21bVSiNaicw==']")
list_element.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "button").click()
```

Comment: I cannot use the class name because it's not unique to the button I want to use and it might click the incorrect one.

Comment: Do you care to share the web page you are using?

Comment: I mentioned the website and what I was trying to accomplish to the question. I am also a beginner in selenium and python.

Answer (score 1):

> I have also tried to do By.XPATH
> "//button[@data-target-section-id='RIK0XK7NRnS21bVSiNaicw==']")"" but
> it also does not find it.

The **data-target-section-id** that you mention is **not the same** as the one that the button has (PTFmMNSPSz2LQRzwynhRBQ==). Check that this is not dynamic before targeting it.

Your xPath is not bad but as I told you, fix the target-id:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@data-target-section-id='PTFmMNSPSz2LQRzwynhRBQ==']")).click()
```

Where "driver" is your WebDriver instance.

Comment: what do you mean it is not the same? Could you further explain what you mean by this?

Comment: Your xPath is targeting data-target-section-id='RIK0XK7NRnS21bVSiNaicw==' and in your code, the xPath is data-target-section-id="PTFmMNSPSz2LQRzwynhRBQ=="

Comment: oh I see now what you meant. I copied it directly from the page and it still does not find it through. I suspect it's dynamic as you mentioned but even if I add a wait time and change the xpath to wait for it like someone else mentioned it does not find it.

Comment: Use [xPath Finder](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-finder/ihnknokegkbpmofmafnkoadfjkhlogph) and grab the xPath regardless of the button values.

Comment: xPath Finder did not help find the xPath either

Comment: Please provide the HTML code. We cannot give you any solution in any other way. Another solution is to take a non-dynamic parent element and look for buttons inside that element.

Answer (score 0):

Given the HTML:

```
<li>
   <button aria-current="false" class="search-navigation-panel_button" data-target-section-id="PTFmMNSPSz2LQRzwynhRBQ==" role="link" type="button"> People </button>
</li>
```

The *data-target-section-id* attribute values like *`PTFmMNSPSz2LQRzwynhRBQ==`* are dynamically generated and is bound to chage sooner/later. They may change next time you access the application afresh or even while next application startup. So can't be used in locators.

---

### Solution

The desired element being a dynamic element to click on the ***clickable*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.search-navigation-panel_button[data-target-section-id]"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='search-navigation-panel_button' and @data-target-section-id][contains(., 'People')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: It times out. I tried increasing the time it waits to a full minute but it continues to timeout with both CSS_SELECTOR and XPATH options

Comment: Does the HTML in my answer matches to the actual html at your end?

Comment: Looking it more closely it looks like the class didn't match correctly, however, I do not know how to make it match because of the format. 

The class is as follows:
class="search-navigation-panel__button
              search-navigation-panel__button--active"

How can I account for the 2nd line in the class?

Comment: the comment does not correctly reflect the gap. It's class="search-navigation-panel__button \n
              search-navigation-panel__button--active"